# Choosing field names while finding results from two tables

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have two tables (which happen to be in two different databases). "clients" and "domains", clients can have multiple domains.

This is the code i am using:

```
$this->Domain->find('all', array(
    'order' => 'domain ASC',
    'fields' => array(
        'Domain.id',
        'Domain.domain',
        'Server.name',
        'Client.id',
        'Client.name'
    )
));
```

When i return all the fields by not using the 'fields' => array() everything works fine, as soon as i ask for specific fields, it says:

> SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column
>   'Client.id' in 'field list'

Everything also works fine if i just remove the two Client columns (The Client model is the only model which is on another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If clients `hasMany` domains, So your models should be called like `$this->Domain->find('all');` explicitly passing fields `Client.id` will show error, as its not the part of domains table, enable sql dumping using `debug=2` and see how queries are being run.

You models should be

```
// in client.php model - having structure - id, name
$hasMany = 'Domain';

// in domain.php model - having structure - id, name, client_id
$belongsTo = 'Client';
```

This should work like this

```
$this->Domain->recursive = 1;
$data = $this->Domain->find('all');
// $data = Array ( 'Domain' => ********, 'Client' => ****** )
```

Comment: He states that his two tables (domains and clients) are in separate databases -- I think his issue is in trying to span different dbs.

Comment: But it lets me use the column "Server.name" which is part of a different table?

Answer (score 0):

If your two tables are in different databases, you're really making your life difficult.  AFAIK, Cake doesn't support joining two tables (or enforcing relationships) between two different databases.  Why do you have the client table in a separate db?

If you can't move your table, I think you're going to have to write some custom code inside your Domain model, so that it will use the (default) db connection string for domains, but will instantiate and connect another db resource to the other database.  See http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/doze/2010/03/12/use-multiple-databases-in-one-app-based-on-requested-url for how to do it -- skip ahead to the section entitled, "Select Correct Database Dynamically".

HTH,
Travis

Comment: I have them in another database because im borrowing them from another website and I dont want any duplication. I managed ot get multiple databases to work fine by using:
var $useDbConfig = 'anotherdb';

Comment: Right, but I don't think you can change the dbConfig var in the middle of a query, can you?  Seems like you'll still need to create a custom find method.

Comment: An alternate idea would be for you to create a trigger on the other database table.  On a create/update/delete, trigger it to mirror the data in the other db.

Comment: Im not having a problem with multiple databases, changing $useDbConfig in the model works fine. The problem i am having is being able to chose what columns i return simply to speed things up. when i ask for columns from the clients table it says they dont exist.

Comment: Right, that's because the find() method won't normally pull from separate databases, which is what you're trying to do with your query.  You need to override your Model::find() so that it will do that.  I would still suggest putting everything together in one database; unless there is an extremely compelling reason, it'll make your life a lot easier.  Why not just add your Cake-app tables to your other website's database?  You can always remove them later as needed.